# keepSynced(true) doesn't fetch the data for the location immediately

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As the title mentioned, I get local data with keepSynced(true) and have to go out and back into the view to get the latest (fresh) data.

i have the following setup:

```
var baseRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
baseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
baseRef.child("Posts").keepSynced(true)
```

then in viewWillAppear:

```
baseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("sortTimestamp").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in //etc
```

I get local data, according to this post the data should be fresh as I keepSynced before I attach an observer:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/keepSynced/firebase-talk/SK9WVZvkHsU/HVjxtnv5JoYJ

"keepSynced will work fine both with disk persistence enabled and with it disabled. It immediately fetches the data for the location/query where you enable it, before you attach a listener"

However, as mentioned, I have to trigger this again, by going out and in of the viewController(almost like a refresh), to get fresh data

I did try the normal observeEventType(.Value as well as .ChildAdded, but with the pagination system I use observeSingleEventOfType works better except for the issues above

Not sure what I am missing, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I think it works as expected. Using observeSingleEventOfType, the block is immediately canceled after the initial data is returned.

Comment: Correct @gRenzFries. It sounds like you're getting a race condition there: while the data is being refreshed, you may see stale data. In general: don't use `observeSingleEventOfType` when you're using disk persistence.

Comment: Strange, but ok. I'll have to go back and make .ChildAdded work, I guess. thank you.